# How to get wrapping in tables while using Siunitx?

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx, booktabs

Like the title suggests, I'd like to use the S[table-format = xyz] form in my tables, while having the longer headers be wrapped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Pipettierschema Teilversuch 2}
\label{tab:ps2}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format = 1.3] S[table-format = 3.0] c c c c @{}} 
\toprule
{nº} & {Pyruvatkonzentration} & {Bidestilliertes Wasser} & {Pyruvat} & {Imidazolpuffer} & {NADH} & {Lactat}\\ 
\midrule
  1 & 0,01 & 878 & 20 & 5 & 2 & 0 \\
  2 & 0,015 & 877 & 20 & 15 & 2 & 0 \\ 
  3 & 0,02 & 876 & 20 & 25 & 2 & 0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

[image: The table is too wide using S mode]

In this case, I'd like the "Pyruvatkonzentration" and/or "Bidestilliertes Wasser" to get wrapped, but for the numbers to retain the Siuntix appearance. Preferably, I'd love to set it up in the preamble, or within the code for the table itself, and have it wrap the words for me, and not manually set each hyphenation in each word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\multicolumn{1}{…}{…}` to specify another column type for the heads, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\TableHead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{p{4em}}{\centering\hskip0pt#1}}
  
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Pipettierschema Teilversuch 2}
\label{tab:ps2}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format = 1.3] S[table-format = 3.0] c c c c @{}} 
\toprule
{nº} & \TableHead{Pyruvatkonzentration} & \TableHead{Bidestilliertes Wasser} & {Pyruvat} & \TableHead{Imidazolpuffer} & {NADH} & {Lactat}\\ 
\midrule
  1 & 0,01 & 878 & 20 & 5 & 2 & 0 \\
  2 & 0,015 & 877 & 20 & 15 & 2 & 0 \\ 
  3 & 0,02 & 876 & 20 & 25 & 2 & 0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also need to specify the width of the some columns for the heads, you can define, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\TableHead}{O{4em}m}{\multicolumn{1}{p{#1}}{\centering\hskip0pt#2}}
  
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Pipettierschema Teilversuch 2}
\label{tab:ps2}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format = 1.3] S[table-format = 3.0] c c c c @{}} 
\toprule
{nº} & \TableHead[6em]{Pyruvatkonzentration} & \TableHead[6em]{Bidestilliertes Wasser} & {Pyruvat} & \TableHead{Imidazolpuffer} & {NADH} & {Lactat}\\ 
\midrule
  1 & 0,01 & 878 & 20 & 5 & 2 & 0 \\
  2 & 0,015 & 877 & 20 & 15 & 2 & 0 \\ 
  3 & 0,02 & 876 & 20 & 25 & 2 & 0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple is with `tblr` of `tabularray` package. No need to define command for column headers, text in column headers is hyphenate by adding `cmd=\hskip0pt` to specification for the first table row:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} c X[c, si={table-format=1.3}]
                              X[c, si={table-format=3.0}]
                         *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]}
                         *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=1.0}]}
                        @{} },
             row{1}  = {guard, f, cmd=\hskip0pt} 
            }
    \toprule
nº  & Pyruvatkonzentration 
            & Bidestilliertes Wasser    
                    & Pyruvat   & Imidazolpuffer    
                                        & NADH  & Lactat    \\
    \midrule
  1 & 0,01  & 878   & 20        & 5     & 2     & 0         \\
  2 & 0,015 & 877   & 20        & 15    & 2     & 0         \\
  3 & 0,02  & 876   & 20        & 25    & 2     & 0         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your solution, yet for me the table is still buggy. The only wrapped section is the "Bidestilliertes Wasser". The "Pyruvatkonzentration" and "Imidazolpuffer" go out of bounds: [link](https://imgur.com/a/8bO22h2)